# Grey horizontal lines across screen google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-api

For some reason I have grey horizontal lines across the google maps view-box.

If you would have removed the lines and stitched the map back together, then the map would fit together as if you put back together a torn map for example.

Did anyone encounter this and what is the solution to it?
I read some snippets (i forgot where) that it has to do with css. 
I tried to play around with different combination of css and nothing seems to affect it.

Thanks in advance.
Jenia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to detect the source usually(at least for me) is to use the developer-tools.

1. go to the HTML/Elements-tab and select an img-element that is a map-tile
2. inspect the styles that have been applied to this image in the style-tab on the right side(except `element.style`)
3. regarding to your description the problematic styles may be width/maxwidth when not 256, border, margin, padding
4. when you've detected an problematic setting try to change  or remove the value, you should immediately see the changes
5. when you didn't find anything repeat the steps for the parent `<div>` of the `<img>`

To easily find the images execute this inside the console:

```
console.dir(document.querySelectorAll('img[src*="googleapis.com/vt?lyrs="]'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have your browser zoomed.. return to the default zoom (100%) and the lines will disappear.

Comment: Played with zoom on my instance of the bug. Was reproducible at all levels of browser zoom.